# How to avoid keyboard layout automatically changing on windows phone 8

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

My problem is when I change the region, then the keyboard language is changed. I don't want to this. I want a static keybord in the whole application.

Actually I have one calculator form when I change region us to South Africa than it will take `,` instant of `.`

How to solve this problem?

Help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the keyboard symbols depend upon phone language. You need to get ride of This when converting the text input to a double, using the `double.parse` or `double.tryparse` methods and using the `cultureinvariant` formatter.